# using R How do I retain a sentence with a key word

Tags: r, string, grepl, keyword-search

I have dataset as shown below

```
   Id     Comments
   1      How. will the binary giant change. 
          Will the unknown disregard maximize another blamed bottle?
   2      The thinking accent hurts.... How.. the lord coast?
   3      The panda moans about the intuitive room past a device.
   4      In an ideology punts the center..
          How. An exercise elaborates past a photographic bookshop
```

I want to retain sentences that contain the keyword `How` and not case sensitive

The final dataset should look like this

```
   Id     Comments
   1      How will the binary giant change. 
   2      How the lord coast?
   3      NA
   4      How An exercise elaborates past a photographic bookshop
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are these sentences separated by `\n` within the 'Id'`

Comment: @akrun, some by `.` and some are by \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
gsub('[.](?!$)', '', 
       str_extract(df1$Comments, "\\bHow.*(\\?|\\.|$)"), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "How will the binary giant change."                       
#[2] "How the lord coast?"                                    
#[3] NA                                                       
#[4] "How An exercise elaborates past a photographic bookshop"
```

Comment: @akurn, it works if the sentences are seperated by only one `.` but what if  the sentence is seperated by random dots , i mean, some are `.` some are `....` some are `..`

Comment: @ErnestPresley  I can only check based on the example you showed.  Based on the expected output you showed, it works.

Comment: @ErnestPresley  Please edit your question with such case.

Comment: @akrun, my apologise, i updated my questions some random dot scenario now.

Comment: @ErnestPresley  Have you tried the solutions above?  It is working for me with the updated post.

Comment: @akrun, some grep and grepl functions but nothing very exciting

Comment: @ErnestPresley  I meant by using your updated example, I am getting the expected output.

Comment: @akrun I am working on it now give me few minutes, i will reply if I run into any problems (hope not)

Comment: @ErnestPresley  You can also try `str_extract(df1$Comments, "\\bHow(\\s\\S+)+(\\?|\\.|$)")` if the above doesn't work

Comment: @akrun, there are some sentences with random `.` before and after the keyword (How) and this is causing some problems. I updated my question with this scenario as well :(

Comment: @ErnestPresley  Please let me know if this is the last you are updating.

Comment: @ErnestPresley  I got the expected output with the update.  Please check the change in the code.

Comment: @akrun, for some reason all the spaces between the text were gone, but I will take it. Thanks Akrun

Comment: @ErnestPresley  I am matching the regex with the text you provided.  So, if there is any inconsistency, it may have problems.

Comment: @akrun, i did one small trick , i changed this `gsub('[.](?!$)', '',` to `gsub('[.](?!$)', ' ',` and it worked

Comment: @ErnestPresley  Thanks for the feedback.  Glad it helped.

Comment: @akrun, happy ending :)